# How to replicate index/match (with multiple criteria) in in python with multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I am trying to replicate a excel model I have in python to automate it as I scale it up but I am stuck on how to translate the complex formula's into python.

I have information in three dataframes:

DF1:

| ID type 1 | ID type 2 | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1_a | 400 |
| b | 1_b | 26 |
| c | 1_c | 23 |
| d | 1_b | 45 |
| e | 1_d | 24 |
| f | 1_b | 85 |
| g | 1_a | 98 |

DF2:

| ID type 1 | ID type 2 | Tech |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1_a | wind |
| b | 1_b | solar |
| c | 1_c | gas |
| d | 1_b | coal |
| e | 1_d | wind |
| f | 1_b | gas |
| g | 1_a | coal |

And DF 3, the main DF:

| Date | Time | ID type 1 | ID type 2 | Period | output | Unit * | Tech * |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/01/2022 | 02:30:00 | a | 1_a | 1 | 254 |  |  |
| 03/01/2022 | 02:30:00 | b | 1_b | 1 | 456 |  |  |
| 03/01/2022 | 02:30:00 | c | 1_c | 2 | 3325 |  |  |
| 03/01/2022 | 02:30:00 | d | 1_b | 2 | 1254 |  |  |
| 05/01/2022 | 02:30:00 | e | 1_d | 3 | 489 |  |  |
| 05/01/2022 | 02:30:00 | a | 1_a | 3 | 452 |  |  |
| 05/01/2022 | 02:30:00 | b | 1_b | 4 | 12 |  |  |
| 05/01/2022 | 02:30:00 | c | 1_c | 4 | 1 |  |  |
| 05/01/2022 | 03:00:00 | d | 1_b | 35 | 54 |  |  |
| 05/01/2022 | 03:00:00 | e | 1_d | 35 | 48 |  |  |
| 05/01/2022 | 03:00:00 | a | 1_a | 48 | 56 |  |  |

I wish to get the information from each ID type in DF 3 for "unit" and "Tech" from DF 1 & 2 into DF 3. The conditional statements I have in excel atm are based on INDEX and MATCH and INFA, as some of the ID types in DF will be from either ID type 1 or ID type 2 so the function checks both columns and based on a positve match yields the required result.

For more context, DF1 and DF2 do not change but DF3 changes and I need a function for that which I will explain later.

The excel function I use to fill in Unit* from DF1 is (note I have replaced the excel sheet name to DF1 to help conceptualize the problem:

```
=IFNA(INDEX('DF1'!$K$3:$K$1011,MATCH(N2,'DF1'!$E$3:$E$1011,0)),INDEX('DF1'!$K$3:$K$1011,MATCH(M2,'DF1'!$D$3:$D$1011,0)))
```

The excel function I use to fill in Tech * is a bit more straight forward:

```
=IFNA(INDEX('DF2'$L:$L,MATCH(O3,'DF2'$K:$K,0)),INDEX('DF2'$L:$L,MATCH(N3,'DF2'$J:$J,0)))
```

That is the main stumbling block at the moment, but after this is achieved I need a function that for each day produces the following DF:

| ID type 1 | Tech | Period 1 | Period 2 | Period 3 | Period 4 | Period 5 | Period 6 | Period 7 | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | wind | Sum of output for this ID Type 1 and Period 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| b | solar |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| c | gas |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| d | coal |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| e | wind |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| a | gas |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| … | … |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The idea here is that I can use conditional function again to sum the "output" column of DF3 under the condition of date, ID type and period number.

```
EDIT: Output based on possible solution:

           time settlementDate BM Unit ID 1 BM Unit ID 2  settlementPeriod  \
0      00:00:00     03/01/2022      RCBKO-1    T_RCBKO-1                 1   
1      00:00:00     03/01/2022      LARYO-3    T_LARYW-3                 1   
2      00:00:00     03/01/2022       LAGA-1     T_LAGA-1                 1   
3      00:00:00     03/01/2022      CRMLW-1    T_CRMLW-1                 1   
4      00:00:00     03/01/2022      GRIFW-1    T_GRIFW-1                 1   
...         ...            ...          ...          ...               ...   
52533  23:30:00     08/01/2022      CRMLW-1    T_CRMLW-1                48   
52534  23:30:00     08/01/2022      LARYO-4    T_LARYW-4                48   
52535  23:30:00     08/01/2022      HOWBO-3    T_HOWBO-3                48   
52536  23:30:00     08/01/2022      BETHW-1    E_BETHW-1                48   
52537  23:30:00     08/01/2022      HMGTO-1    T_HMGTO-1                48   

       quantity  Capacity_x  Technology  Technology_x  \
0       278.658         NaN          NaN         WIND   
1       162.940         NaN          NaN         WIND   
2       262.200         NaN          NaN         CCGT   
3         3.002         NaN          NaN         WIND   
4         9.972         NaN          NaN         WIND   
...         ...         ...          ...          ...   
52533     8.506         NaN          NaN         WIND   
52534   159.740         NaN          NaN         WIND   
52535    32.554         NaN          NaN          NaN   
52536     5.010         NaN          NaN         WIND   
52537    92.094         NaN          NaN         WIND   

      Registered Resource Name_x  Capacity_y Technology_y  \
0                            NaN         NaN         WIND   
1                            NaN         NaN         WIND   
2                            NaN         NaN         CCGT   
3                            NaN         NaN         WIND   
4                            NaN         NaN         WIND   
...                          ...         ...          ...   
52533                        NaN         NaN         WIND   
52534                        NaN         NaN         WIND   
52535                        NaN         NaN          NaN   
52536                        NaN         NaN         WIND   
52537                        NaN         NaN         WIND   

      Registered Resource Name_y  Capacity  
0                            NaN       NaN  
1                            NaN       NaN  
2                            NaN       NaN  
3                            NaN       NaN  
4                            NaN       NaN  
...                          ...       ...  
52533                        NaN       NaN  
52534                        NaN       NaN  
52535                        NaN       NaN  
52536                        NaN       NaN  
52537                        NaN       NaN  

[52538 rows x 14 columns]
```

EDIT: New query

| ID Type 1 | Tech | Period_1 | Period_2 | Period_3 | Period_4 | Period_35 | Period_48 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | wind | 450 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | >>> These are mean of all dates* |
| b | wind | 0 | 0 | 550 | 0 | 0 | 85 |  |
| b | wind | 0 | 0 | 895 | 0 | 452 | 0 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Please have a quick look on how to provide data here on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You shouldn't add data as images... instead copy paste them as text to your question.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I had an issue where it came up in the review but then when I posted they were not visible. I have added using HTML markup now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question you want to do a left merge on those 2 columns twice like this:

```
df3 = (
    df3
    .merge(df1, on=['ID type 1', 'ID type 2'], how='left')
    .merge(df2, on=['ID type 1', 'ID type 2'], how='left')
)
print(df3)
```

```
          Date      Time ID type 1 ID type 2  Period  output  Unit   Tech
0   03/01/2022  02:30:00         a       1_a       1     254   400   wind
1   03/01/2022  02:30:00         b       1_b       1     456    26  solar
2   03/01/2022  02:30:00         c       1_c       2    3325    23    gas
3   03/01/2022  02:30:00         d       1_b       2    1254    45   coal
4   05/01/2022  02:30:00         e       1_d       3     489    24   wind
5   05/01/2022  02:30:00         a       1_a       3     452   400   wind
6   05/01/2022  02:30:00         b       1_b       4      12    26  solar
7   05/01/2022  02:30:00         c       1_c       4       1    23    gas
8   05/01/2022  03:00:00         d       1_b      35      54    45   coal
9   05/01/2022  03:00:00         e       1_d      35      48    24   wind
10  05/01/2022  03:00:00         a       1_a      48      56   400   wind
```

For the next part you could use a [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

```
out = (
    df3
    .pivot_table(
        index=['Date', 'ID type 1', 'Tech'], 
        columns='Period', 
        values='output', 
        aggfunc=sum, 
        fill_value=0)
    .add_prefix('Period_')
)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
Period                      Period_1  Period_2  Period_3  Period_4  Period_35  Period_48
Date       ID type 1 Tech                                                               
03/01/2022 a         wind        254         0         0         0          0          0
           b         solar       456         0         0         0          0          0
           c         gas           0      3325         0         0          0          0
           d         coal          0      1254         0         0          0          0
05/01/2022 a         wind          0         0       452         0          0         56
           b         solar         0         0         0        12          0          0
           c         gas           0         0         0         1          0          0
           d         coal          0         0         0         0         54          0
           e         wind          0         0       489         0         48          0
```

I used fill_value to show you that option, without it you get 'NaN' in those cells.

**UPDATE**:
From question in comments, only get pivot data of one Technology (e.g. 'wind'):

```
out.loc[out.index.get_level_values('Tech')=='wind']
```

```
Period                     Period_1  Period_2  Period_3  Period_4  Period_35  Period_48
Date       ID type 1 Tech                                                              
03/01/2022 a         wind       254         0         0         0          0          0
05/01/2022 a         wind         0         0       452         0          0         56
           e         wind         0         0       489         0         48          0
```

Comment: I initially thought of using Merge, but my two dataframes that have information for df3 are not the same as df3. For example, there will be multiple dates and periods in df3 for the same id type whereas in df1 and df2 it is a set number if that makes sense. I thought you can only merge the same size.

Comment: That is why I used `how='left'` to assure that df3 stays the same size, if there is a match data of df1 gets merged, if not, there will be a NaN

Comment: [Pandas merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) is a very good post on all kinds of different possibilities to merge data with pandas for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the link I will have a look. I think I did a bad job at explaining the problem with examples as I can see how the solution will run into problems. The data in DF1 will be different when I get to automating it and it has a list of data that is recorded for each unit type for each half hour of each day for say a year. DF1 and DF2 are a set of data like all number of units possible in the DF3 and then criteira for them. Using your solution I dont get a dataframe:

Comment: I have added the output in the post

Comment: oh, I just saw I overlooked the date part in the last step. I only grouped the data by IDtype and Tech. That would be an easy fix, just add `date` to the group in "index" in the pivot.

Comment: Regarding the other issue of merging the data and how df1 will be different, I think I still don't quite understand what 1) your real data is different from your example data 2) why we can't do it like I suggested.

Comment: Okay it's working now, but not 100% and as I mentioned it came down to how poorly I explained it. Basically the two DFs 1 & 2 that I am reading the information from have different columns for the unit id's. So in an instance where unit ID one doesn't match, it would take unit ID two. But based on the NaN's I think it only takes it when there is a match in both unit ID 1 and 2. Is there a way around this similar to the excel IF and IFNA statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249142/discussion-between-rabinzel-and-chetan-patel).

Comment: For the pivot, do you know how I can filter it so it only shows technology = "CCGT"?

Comment: @ChetanPatel I updated my answer for the filter of the pivot.

Comment: Thanks, if I wanted to do multiple inputs, would I be able to pass a string?

Comment: then use `isin`. Like this: `out.loc[out.index.get_level_values('Tech').isin(['wind', 'gas'])]`

Comment: Thank you that worked. For the last bit with the pivot, is there anyway to do the whole step but instead of it indexing each individual day, it aggregates for all dates that were in the df? So it's an aggregate mean in the values and only has ID Type and Technology as the main columns followed by periods. I have managed to shift the headers down by reseting the index but not sure how to aggregate by the dates so it shows all withni the pivot function. Maybe I need another function.

Comment: @ChetanPatel hm I'm not sure if I understand. Could you maybe show your desired result in your question based on the example data I used in my answer? I think that will clarify it.

Comment: Edited, thank you. I can show the edited DF with reset index but that is a few steps ahead. I think I can manage if I figure out how to do the pivot with the aggregate mean for all dates for dates for now.

Comment: I tried to remove the date from the initial pivot index but that did not seem to work

Comment: What about the `id type 1` ? in your example output we only see `Tech` as index.

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake in copy and pasting

Comment: Did you also think of changing the aggfunc from `sum` to `mean`. You want the mean you said, right?

Comment: Yes, I didn't change the agg function as from my understanding the default is the mean

Comment: but I used 'sum'  in my original answer. I just wanted you to know to be aware of. Mean is the default that is correct.

Comment: also you have two rows with id `b` which isn't possible in pivot, I guess typo while copy paste? and: how do you get the 450 for first row id `a` & `period_1`?

Comment: They are just arbitrary examples. There shouldn’t be any repeats all unique values in Id type

Comment: essentially if I remove the .loc step I get the desired result, except I lose the filter on technology

Comment: This gets to messy, I'm a little confused tbh. Maybe it is the best if you just ask a new question with this specific task. Please also pay attention to provide a correct desired output, so I can compare the results I got when testing it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74278469/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-new-dataframe-with-existing-ones-of-different-s Thank you I have now posted it as a sep question and tried to ensure all data is well explained

Comment: I have posted a new one hoping you may be able to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74547501/best-way-to-pass-multiple-conditions-in-pandas-between-dataframes similar issues @rabinzel