# What is the best way to create a new dataframe with existing ones of different shapes and criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a few dataframes that I have made through various sorting and processing of data from the main dataframe (df1).

`df1` - large and will currently covers 6 days worth of data for every 30 mins but I wish to scale up to longer periods:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bmu_units = pd.read_csv('bmu_units_technology.csv')

b1610 = pd.read_csv('b1610_df.csv')

b1610 = (b1610.merge(bmu_units, on=['BM Unit ID 1'], how='left'))

b1610['% of capacity running'] = b1610.quantity / b1610.Capacity

def func(tech):
    if tech in ["CCGT","OCGT","COAL"]:
        return "Fossil"
    else:
        return "ZE"
        
b1610["Type"] = b1610['Technology'].apply(func)
```

```
      settlementDate      time BM Unit ID 1 BM Unit ID 2_x settlementPeriod quantity BM Unit ID 2_y Capacity     Technology % of capacity running    Type
0         03/01/2022  00:00:00      RCBKO-1      T_RCBKO-1                1  278.658      T_RCBKO-1    279.0           WIND              0.998774      ZE
1         03/01/2022  00:00:00      LARYO-3      T_LARYW-3                1  162.940      T_LARYW-3    180.0           WIND              0.905222      ZE
2         03/01/2022  00:00:00       LAGA-1       T_LAGA-1                1  262.200       T_LAGA-1    905.0           CCGT              0.289724  Fossil
3         03/01/2022  00:00:00      CRMLW-1      T_CRMLW-1                1    3.002      T_CRMLW-1     47.0           WIND              0.063872      ZE
4         03/01/2022  00:00:00      GRIFW-1      T_GRIFW-1                1    9.972      T_GRIFW-1    102.0           WIND              0.097765      ZE
...              ...       ...          ...            ...              ...      ...            ...      ...            ...                   ...     ...
52533     08/01/2022  23:30:00      CRMLW-1      T_CRMLW-1               48    8.506      T_CRMLW-1     47.0           WIND              0.180979      ZE
52534     08/01/2022  23:30:00      LARYO-4      T_LARYW-4               48  159.740      T_LARYW-4    180.0           WIND              0.887444      ZE
52535     08/01/2022  23:30:00      HOWBO-3      T_HOWBO-3               48   32.554      T_HOWBO-3    440.0  Offshore Wind              0.073986      ZE
52536     08/01/2022  23:30:00      BETHW-1      E_BETHW-1               48    5.010      E_BETHW-1     30.0           WIND              0.167000      ZE
52537     08/01/2022  23:30:00      HMGTO-1      T_HMGTO-1               48   92.094        HMGTO-1    108.0           WIND              0.852722      ZE
```

`df2`:

```
rank = (
b1610.pivot_table(
index=['settlementDate','BM Unit ID 1','Technology'],
columns='settlementPeriod',
values='% of capacity running',
aggfunc=sum,
fill_value=0)
)

rank['rank of capacity'] = rank.sum(axis=1)
rank
```

```
settlementPeriod                                        1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10   ...         40         41         42         43         44         45         46         47         48  rank of capacity
settlementDate  BM Unit ID 1  Technology                                                                                                                                                                                
03/01/2022      ABRBO-1       WIND               0.936970   0.969293   0.970909   0.925051   0.885657   0.939394   0.963434   0.938586   0.863232   0.781212   ...   0.461818   0.394545   0.428889   0.537172   0.520606   0.545253   0.873333   0.697778   0.651111         29.566263
                ABRTW-1       WIND               0.346389   0.343333   0.345389   0.341667   0.342222   0.346778   0.347611   0.347722   0.346833   0.340556   ...   0.018778   0.015889   0.032056   0.043056   0.032167   0.109611   0.132111   0.163278   0.223556         10.441333
                ACHRW-1       WIND               0.602884   0.575628   0.602140   0.651070   0.667721   0.654791   0.539209   0.628698   0.784233   0.782140   ...   0.174419   0.148465   0.139860   0.091535   0.094698   0.272419   0.205023   0.184651   0.177628         18.517814
                AKGLW-2       WIND               0.000603   0.000603   0.000603   0.000635   0.000603   0.000635   0.000635   0.000635   0.000635   0.000603   ...   0.191079   0.195079   0.250476   0.281048   0.290000   0.279524   0.358508   0.452698   0.572730          8.616032
                ANSUW-1       WIND               0.889368   0.865053   0.915684   0.894000   0.888526   0.858211   0.875158   0.878421   0.809368   0.898737   ...   0.142632   0.212526   0.276421   0.225053   0.235789   0.228000   0.152211   0.226000   0.299158         19.662421
...             ...           ...                     ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...   ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...               ...
08/01/2022      WBURB-2       CCGT               0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   ...   0.636329   0.642447   0.961835   0.908706   0.650212   0.507012   0.513176   0.503576   0.518212         24.439765
                HOWBO-3       Offshore Wind      0.030418   0.026355   0.026595   0.014373   0.012523   0.008418   0.010977   0.016918   0.019127   0.025641   ...   0.055509   0.063845   0.073850   0.073923   0.073895   0.073791   0.073886   0.074050   0.073986          2.332809
                MRWD-1        CCGT               0.808043   0.894348   0.853043   0.650870   0.159783   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   ...   0.701739   0.488913   0.488913   0.489348   0.489130   0.392826   0.079130   0.000000   0.000000         23.485217
                WBURB-3       CCGT               0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   ...   0.771402   0.699986   0.648386   0.919242   0.759520   0.424513   0.430598   0.420089   0.436376         25.436282
                DRAXX-4       BIOMASS            0.706074   0.791786   0.806713   0.806462   0.806270   0.806136   0.806509   0.806369   0.799749   0.825070   ...   0.777395   0.816093   0.707122   0.666639   0.680406   0.679216   0.501433   0.000000   0.000000         36.576512
```

`df3` - this was made by sorting the above dataframe to list sums for each day for each BM Unit ID filtered for specific technology types.

```
   BM Unit ID 1 Technology  03/01/2022  04/01/2022  05/01/2022  06/01/2022  07/01/2022  08/01/2022   ave rank  rank
0        FAWN-1       CCGT         1.0         5.0         1.0         5.0         2.0         1.0   2.500000   1.0
1        GRAI-6       CCGT         4.0        18.0         2.0         4.0         3.0         3.0   5.666667   2.0
2        EECL-1       CCGT         5.0        29.0         4.0         1.0         1.0         2.0   7.000000   3.0
3       PEMB-21       CCGT         7.0         1.0         6.0        13.0         8.0         8.0   7.166667   4.0
4       PEMB-51       CCGT         3.0         3.0         3.0        11.0        16.0         NaN   7.200000   5.0
5       PEMB-41       CCGT         9.0         4.0         7.0         7.0        10.0        13.0   8.333333   6.0
6       WBURB-1       CCGT         6.0         9.0        22.0         2.0         7.0         5.0   8.500000   7.0
7       PEMB-31       CCGT        14.0         6.0        13.0         6.0         4.0         9.0   8.666667   8.0
8        GRMO-1       CCGT         2.0         7.0        10.0        24.0        11.0         6.0  10.000000   9.0
9       PEMB-11       CCGT        21.0         2.0         9.0        10.0         9.0        14.0  10.833333  10.0
10       STAY-1       CCGT        19.0        12.0         5.0        23.0         6.0         7.0  12.000000  11.0
11       GRAI-7       CCGT        10.0        27.0        15.0         9.0        15.0        11.0  14.500000  12.0
12       DIDCB6       CCGT        28.0        11.0        11.0         8.0        19.0        15.0  15.333333  13.0
13       STAY-4       CCGT        12.0         8.0        20.0        18.0        14.0        23.0  15.833333  14.0
14       SCCL-3       CCGT        17.0        16.0        31.0         3.0        18.0        10.0  15.833333  14.0
15       CDCL-1       CCGT        13.0        22.0         8.0        25.0        12.0        16.0  16.000000  15.0
16       STAY-3       CCGT         8.0        17.0        17.0        20.0        13.0        22.0  16.166667  16.0
17       MRWD-1       CCGT         NaN         NaN        19.0        26.0         5.0        19.0  17.250000  17.0
18      WBURB-3       CCGT         NaN         NaN        24.0        14.0        17.0        17.0  18.000000  18.0
19      WBURB-2       CCGT         NaN        14.0        21.0        12.0        31.0        18.0  19.200000  19.0
20       GYAR-1       CCGT         NaN        26.0        14.0        17.0        20.0        21.0  19.600000  20.0
21       STAY-2       CCGT        18.0        20.0        18.0        21.0        24.0        20.0  20.166667  21.0
22       SHOS-1       CCGT        16.0        15.0        28.0        15.0        29.0        27.0  21.666667  22.0
23     KLYN-A-1       CCGT         NaN        24.0        12.0        19.0        27.0        29.0  22.200000  23.0
24       DIDCB5       CCGT         NaN        10.0        35.0        22.0         NaN         NaN  22.333333  24.0
25       CARR-1       CCGT         NaN        33.0        26.0        27.0        22.0         4.0  22.400000  25.0
26       LAGA-1       CCGT        15.0        13.0        29.0        32.0        23.0        24.0  22.666667  26.0
27       CARR-2       CCGT        24.0        25.0        27.0        29.0        21.0        12.0  23.000000  27.0
28       GRAI-8       CCGT        11.0        28.0        36.0        16.0        26.0        25.0  23.666667  28.0
29       SCCL-2       CCGT        29.0         NaN        16.0        28.0        25.0         NaN  24.500000  29.0
30       LBAR-1       CCGT         NaN        19.0        25.0        31.0        28.0         NaN  25.750000  30.0
31      CNQPS-2       CCGT        20.0         NaN        32.0         NaN        32.0        26.0  27.500000  31.0
32       SPLN-1       CCGT         NaN         NaN        23.0        30.0        30.0         NaN  27.666667  32.0
33      CNQPS-1       CCGT        25.0         NaN        33.0         NaN         NaN         NaN  29.000000  33.0
34       DAMC-1       CCGT        23.0        21.0        38.0        34.0         NaN         NaN  29.000000  33.0
35       KEAD-2       CCGT        30.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  30.000000  34.0
36       HUMR-1       CCGT        22.0        30.0        37.0        37.0        33.0        28.0  31.166667  35.0
37       SHBA-1       CCGT        26.0        23.0        40.0        35.0        37.0         NaN  32.200000  36.0
38       SEAB-1       CCGT         NaN        32.0        34.0        36.0         NaN        30.0  33.000000  37.0
39      CNQPS-4       CCGT        27.0         NaN        41.0        33.0        35.0        31.0  33.400000  38.0
40       PETEM1       CCGT         NaN        35.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  35.000000  39.0
41       SEAB-2       CCGT         NaN        31.0        39.0        39.0        34.0         NaN  35.750000  40.0
42       COSO-1       CCGT         NaN         NaN        30.0        42.0        36.0         NaN  36.000000  41.0
43       ROCK-1       CCGT        31.0        34.0        42.0        38.0        38.0         NaN  36.600000  42.0
44     WBURB-43       COAL        32.0        37.0        45.0        40.0        39.0        32.0  37.500000  43.0
45     WBURB-41       COAL        33.0        38.0        46.0        41.0        40.0        33.0  38.500000  44.0
46       FELL-1       CCGT        34.0        39.0        47.0        43.0        41.0        34.0  39.666667  45.0
47      FDUNT-1       OCGT         NaN        36.0        44.0         NaN         NaN         NaN  40.000000  46.0
48       KEAD-1       CCGT         NaN         NaN        43.0         NaN         NaN         NaN  43.000000  47.0
```

My issue is that I am trying to create a new dataframe using the existing dataframes listed above in which I can list all my `BM Unit ID 1's` in order of `rank` from `df2` while populating the values with means of values for all dates (not split by date) in `df1`. An example of what I am after is below, which I made on excel using index match. Here I have the results for each settlement period from `df1` and `df2` but instead of split by date they are an aggregated mean over all dates in the df but they are still ranked according to the last column of `df2`, which is key.

Desired Output:

```
              BM Unit ID Technology       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24      25      26      27
Rank Capacity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
1    150          FAWN-1       CCGT  130.43  130.93  130.78  130.58  130.57  130.54  130.71  130.87  130.89  130.98  130.83  130.80  130.88  131.02  130.81  130.65  130.86  130.84  131.19  130.60  130.69  130.70  130.40  130.03  130.13  130.03  129.75
2    455          GRAI-6       CCGT  339.45  342.33  322.53  312.40  303.78  307.60  316.35  277.18  293.48  325.75  326.75  271.34  299.74  328.06  317.12  342.66  364.50  390.90  403.32  411.52  400.18  405.94  394.04  400.08  389.08  382.74  374.76
3    408          EECL-1       CCGT  363.31  386.71  364.46  363.31  363.31  363.38  361.87  305.06  286.99  282.74  323.93  242.88  242.64  207.73  294.71  357.15  383.47  426.93  433.01  432.98  435.14  436.38  416.04  417.69  430.42  415.09  406.45
4    430         PEMB-21       CCGT  334.40  419.50  436.70  441.90  440.50  415.80  327.90  323.70  322.70  331.10  367.50  368.40  396.70  259.05  415.95  356.32  386.84  400.00  429.52  435.40  434.84  435.88  435.60  438.48  438.16  437.84  437.76
5    465         PEMB-51       CCGT  370.65  370.45  359.90  326.25  326.20  322.65  324.60  274.25  319.55  288.80  301.75  279.08  379.60  376.76  389.92  419.24  403.64  420.92  428.20  421.32  396.92  397.80  424.40  433.92  434.56  431.44  434.40
6    445         PEMB-41       CCGT  337.00  423.40  423.10  427.50  427.00  419.00  361.00  318.80  263.20  226.70  268.70  231.35  366.90  378.35  392.20  421.55  354.96  382.48  422.64  428.28  428.76  431.24  431.92  431.84  429.52  429.00  431.48
7    425         WBURB-1       CCGT  240.41  293.17  252.27  256.51  261.65  253.44  247.14  217.08  223.11  199.27  254.69  314.16  361.07  317.50  259.54  266.83  349.64  383.43  408.18  412.29  395.54  383.48  355.98  340.49  360.87  352.74  376.92
8    465         PEMB-31       CCGT  297.73  360.27  355.40  357.07  358.67  353.07  300.93  284.73  268.73  255.20  248.53  257.75  366.75  376.45  396.40  320.56  342.68  352.52  361.16  379.40  386.64  390.36  409.12  427.48  426.60  426.80  427.16
9    144          GRMO-1       CCGT  106.62  106.11  105.96  106.00  106.00  105.98  105.99  105.90  105.47  105.31  105.28  105.07  105.04  105.06  105.06  105.04  105.06  105.06  105.07  105.04  105.05  105.06  105.04  105.04  105.04  105.06  105.07
10   430         PEMB-11       CCGT  432.80  430.40  430.70  431.90  432.10  429.30  430.00  408.30  320.90  346.50  432.90  432.20  312.93  297.20  414.55  432.00  420.40  429.80  402.60  426.90  430.65  435.85  435.10  431.15  435.20  431.50  431.75
11   457          STAY-1       CCGT  216.07  223.27  232.67  243.47  234.67  221.73  227.00  219.00  237.00  218.33  250.73  228.27  219.67  142.68  243.00  300.64  312.28  331.00  360.84  379.28  398.92  410.04  410.56  409.24  411.96  408.84  411.88
12   455          GRAI-7       CCGT  425.20  425.40  377.90  339.40  342.00  329.80  408.00  402.40  329.00  257.30  130.43  211.37  262.60  318.45  299.98  324.72  350.40  386.26  394.20  402.10  390.48  401.22  388.94  394.10  395.14  379.70  377.26
13   710          DIDCB6       CCGT  465.80  459.50  411.60  411.70  413.70  410.80  351.50  333.40  333.70  390.40  234.60  265.56  348.16  430.28  524.32  554.04  536.28  589.28  594.04  597.72  592.76  557.86  687.70  687.25  687.35  687.25  679.80
14   400          SCCL-3       CCGT  311.50  337.40  378.80  311.50  381.30  338.60  302.70  300.70  300.60  300.70  338.20  321.50  363.80  260.35  228.18  308.70  334.73  324.60  354.63  362.38  347.30  306.22  346.86  365.04  365.40  370.68  370.52
     400          SCCL-3       CCGT  311.50  337.40  378.80  311.50  381.30  338.60  302.70  300.70  300.60  300.70  338.20  321.50  363.80  260.35  228.18  308.70  334.73  324.60  354.63  362.38  347.30  306.22  346.86  365.04  365.40  370.68  370.52
16   440          CDCL-1       CCGT  270.63  255.24  210.87  197.10  195.12  198.72  197.64  198.99  233.19  221.31  176.94  317.52  280.68  213.12  297.68  342.25  397.26  372.28  371.74  379.87  347.51  348.48  352.15  384.88  395.14  381.02  360.40
17   457          STAY-3       CCGT  311.25  311.30  311.60  311.45  311.15  311.30  308.40  313.10  223.90  196.05  242.95  172.87  217.40  236.84  252.92  352.98  384.06  414.76  403.68  424.90  418.38  403.00  420.26  424.40  427.06  421.64  424.66
18   920          MRWD-1       CCGT  468.70  483.90  420.60  267.80  472.60  470.20  241.40  299.30  327.70  327.80  336.90  241.60  308.33  529.93  793.73  828.40  870.67  846.67  827.07  855.93  829.33  865.87  870.40  846.87  765.47  785.20  824.00
19   425         WBURB-3       CCGT  311.73  427.68  333.68  333.93  370.68  335.09  420.85  433.86  370.45  321.70  340.54  300.95  155.47  190.67  290.81  310.43  332.52  376.63  391.11  413.74  408.33  398.69  397.54  368.05  410.64  413.05  428.91
20   425         WBURB-2       CCGT  295.54  424.56  336.68  334.08  371.20  358.44  358.90  358.96  377.94  325.42  203.19  165.32  205.75  121.41  162.51  180.15  301.12  413.77  410.33  397.21  385.59  378.09  381.50  380.93  413.71  418.53  427.09
21   420          GYAR-1       CCGT  404.33  404.33  403.73  405.12  404.13  404.33  404.33  376.98  218.02  218.02  351.01  215.10  177.46  222.43  345.47  398.94  401.97  401.97  402.17  401.87  401.47  401.77  401.62  402.51  402.31  402.41  402.26
22   457          STAY-2       CCGT  434.20  435.40  435.40  435.20  434.20  434.20  434.20  434.60  249.80  196.20  291.20  234.80  196.80   88.73  167.10  239.52  324.52  372.80  412.40  423.32  424.04  423.96  423.92  424.08  423.88  420.96  422.44
23   400        KLYN-A-1       CCGT  382.58  382.50  384.94  385.81  385.83  385.79  385.02  384.94  259.16  141.03  195.65  205.75  278.81  256.95  296.85  337.82  369.26  376.38  376.84  376.56  376.30  376.09  375.62  375.45  375.11  375.17  375.09
24   420          SHOS-1       CCGT  290.63  326.33  229.60  265.70  269.05  259.40  299.45  310.20  301.65  266.00  307.90  319.30  253.06  246.85  263.04  220.46  277.68  297.84  290.62  297.86  302.83  295.13  293.73  289.04  306.14  314.24  321.76
```

Comment: `df1.pivot_table(index=['Capacity', 'Technology'], columns='BM Unit ID 1', values='quantity', aggfunc='mean')` is that what you want? It's not quite clear to me how rank of df3 is calculated, isn't that just an increasing index of all unique `BM Unit ID 1` keys?

Comment: thanks - rank was calculated from df2, as a sum of all periods for each unit and then put in order of highest to lowest.

Comment: did you try the code? For the columns there is just instead of the ordered Unit ID by sum, the column Unit ID itself, but is the format right?